# (Tkinter)Como deixar Labels, Buttons, e Frames com o fundo tranparente?

Tags: python, tkinter, gui, label

Estou tentando fazer um programa no Python com o Tkinter para fazer registros e etc, porém, ao tentar botar uma foto na imagem de fundo está sendo impossível remover os espaços brancos que o tkinter faz quando vc cria uma label e bota bd, ou um botão.[image: O app aberto.]
A classe master com detalhes que podem ajudar

```
class Window1:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("UnderFox")
        self.master.geometry('1350x750+0+0')
        self.master.iconbitmap("fox.ico")
        self.image = PhotoImage(file="download.png")
        self.image = self.image.subsample(1,1)
        self.labelimage = Label(image=self.image)
        self.labelimage.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1.0, relheight=1.0)
        self.frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.frame.pack()

        self.User = StringVar()
        self.Password = StringVar()
        self.LabelTitle = Label(self.frame, text="Registro Geral", font=('arial', 50,'bold'), bd=20)
        self.LabelTitle.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=20)

        self.Loginframe1 = Frame(self.frame, width=1010, height=300, bd=20, relief='ridge')
        self.Loginframe1.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.Loginframe2 = Frame(self.frame, width=1010, height=100, bd=20, relief='ridge')
        self.Loginframe2.grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.Loginframe3 = Frame(self.frame, width=1010, height=200, bd=20,  relief='ridge')
        self.Loginframe3.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=2)

        self.LabelUser = Label(self.Loginframe1, text="Nome", font=('arial', 30,'bold'), bd=22)
        self.LabelUser.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.txtUser = Entry(self.Loginframe1, text="Nome", font=('arial', 30, 'bold'), bd=22, textvariable=self.User)
        self.txtUser.grid(row=0, column=1)


        self.LabelPassword = Label(self.Loginframe1, text="Senha", font=('arial', 30, 'bold'), bd=22)
        self.LabelPassword.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.txtPassword = Entry(self.Loginframe1, text="Senha", font=('arial', 30, 'bold'), bd=22, textvariable=self.Password)
        self.txtPassword.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.btnLogin = Button(self.Loginframe2, text='Login', width=17,font=('arial',20,'bold'), command=self.Login_System)
        self.btnLogin.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.btnReset = Button(self.Loginframe2, text='Resetar', width=17, font=('arial',20,'bold'), command=self.Reset)
        self.btnReset.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.btnExit = Button(self.Loginframe2, text='Sair',  width=17, font=('arial',20,'bold'), command=self.iExit)
        self.btnExit.grid(row=0, column=2)


        self.btnResgistration = Button(self.Loginframe3, text='Registro Infantil', font=('arial',20,'bold'), state = DISABLED, command=self.resgistration_window)
        self.btnResgistration.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.btnHospital = Button(self.Loginframe3, text='Registro Equipe DI', font=('arial',20,'bold'), state=DISABLED,  command=self.hospital_window)
        self.btnHospital.grid(row=0, column=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

O tkinter não tem suporte a transparência - então infelizmente não existe como.

Você pode criar temas com degradês, reflexos falsificados, fazer várias coisas - mas ele não tem suporte nem a rotação de texto, nem transparência - ele expõe uma API de desenho criada décadas atrás - era e é estável, funciona bem, mas não evoluiu  nos quesitos gráficos.

Então não é possível dizer que o 'frame' onde você monta os seus controles tem fundo transparente ou translucente - se ele existir, tem que ter uma cor sólida.

O que é possível, no entanto, mas não simples, é *não usar* o frame, e adicionar todos os controles diretamente na janela principal (master) - apenas não use o `self.frame` e passe sempre `self.master` em seu lugar, e tente usar as opções `padx`, `pady`, `ipadx` e `ipady` nos seus controles para tentar chegar em um layout agradável (essas são opções que podem ser passadas a chamada `.grid` além das informações de `row` e `column`)

Comment: OK! Muito Obrigado, realmente achava que havia como fazer isso, vou tentar utilizar o self.master. Mas se eu entendi eu teria que remover as frames, usando o master, e colocar em cada label,botão e etc, sua posição específica, e então neste caso sumiria as partes brancas, correto?

Answer (score -1):

se for a tela inteira tem como mais se for somente os whidgth[Button].... nao sei

pra tela inteira o comando é este :

```
from tkinter import *
 
root = Tk()
 
root.geometry("400x400")
 
root.attributes('-alpha',0.5) ##### este aqui , pode variar o numero para ficar mais opaco
 
root.mainloop()
```